# Find the density of T if $P(T \leq t) = 2 \Phi\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt t}\right)$

Tags: probability, statistics

Question in the topic. So basically I want to rearrange $\Phi\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt(t)}\right)$ in such a way so I can show that the density of $T$ equals $$(2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{-x^2/(2t)}xt^{-3/2}.$$ $\Phi$ is the distribution of a standard normal random variable. Feels like it should be quite simply but I've forgotten all my integral manipulation tricks!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just differentiate $P(T\leq t)$, it'll give you the density.